# how to calculate the norm of a vector in a large mxnx3 array?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, vectorization, linear-algebra

Suppose I have an array of the shape (m,n,3), where m and n refers to the y and x coordinates of a point, and the 3 numbers in each point refer to a three-dimensional vector. (A similar situation is an image with height m and width n, and 3 refers to the rgb components).

Suppose I want to normalize each vector to get the normal vector at that point, how to do it efficiently? I only know I can use a nested for loop to loop through each point and use scipy.lialg.norm to get the norm of the vector at that point, then I can get the unit vector by simply dividing. But are there any ways to do it efficiently like using vectorized code?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just divide your array by the sqrt of the sum of squares of your array's last  dimension.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.random.rand(1000, 500, 3)

In [3]: normed = x / np.sqrt((x**2).sum(axis=-1))[:,:,None] 
        #None could be np.newaxis
```

Note that if you want to compute the norm separately then divide the array by the norm, you will need to make sure the shapes are compatible, which they won't be if you just divide a (N, M, 3) array by a (N, M) normed array.  The normed array needs an extra dimension, i.e. (N, M, 1), which can be achieved doing (where `None` and `np.newaxis` can be used interchangeably).

```
normed[...,None], normed[:,:,None], normed.reshape(N, M, 1), etc...
```

Here are the original first and last values:

```
In [4]: x[(0, -1), (0, -1)]
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.36461324,  0.16861872,  0.53603133],
       [ 0.37323254,  0.15314778,  0.1338908 ]])
```

and now normed:

```
In [5]: normed[(0,-1),(0,-1)]
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0.5443173 ,  0.2517245 ,  0.80022088],
       [ 0.87805199,  0.36028936,  0.31498615]])
```